# Querydsl native jpa query return entities instead of object array

Tags: java, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm using **QueryDSL** in my current project, and in one instance I need to use native query instead of jpa one due to **jpql** limitations.

Thankfully it's quite easy to swap from one to another and keep the api abstraction layer by just switching from `JPAQuery` to `JPASQLQuery`, however after I do that the `jpa` entities are no longer mapped as result type.

**Example:**

Using `JPAQuery`:

```
QPriceModel pm = QPriceModel.priceModel;

List<PriceModel> fetch = new JPAQuery<PriceModel>(entityManager)
    .select(pm)
    .from(pm)
    .fetch();
```

Will produce proper entities as result type:

[image]

But `JPASQLQuery`

```
QPriceModel pm = QPriceModel.priceModel;

List<PriceModel> fetch = new JPASQLQuery<PriceModel>(entityManager, new OracleTemplates())
    .select(pm)
    .from(pm)
    .fetch();
```

Will only return column arrays as is

[image: results]

Is there any way to force `JPASQLQuery` to return entities without manually mapping them?

Im using QUERY_DSL_VERSION=4.2.1

---

**TLDR**

Query dsl no longer maps jpa entities after switching from `JPAQuery` to `JPASQLQuery`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that `JPASQLQuery` does not use `DefaultQueryHandler` by default, which is needed to pass a type resolver to the `entityManager` as seen here 
https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/blob/QUERYDSL_4_2_1/querydsl-jpa/src/main/java/com/querydsl/jpa/sql/AbstractJPASQLQuery.java#L105-L113

My solution is to pass the `DefaultQueryHandler` to the constructor of the `JPASQLQuery`

```
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration(new OracleTemplates());

        new JPASQLQuery<>(entityManager, configuration,  DefaultQueryHandler.DEFAULT);
```

This will produce a resolved entity from your select statement